# Is there a record of which programs are running on my screen?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, logs, display

I would like to automatically collect some statistics on how often I use applications on my computer. Are there records of which applications are displaying content on my screen? If so, where are they? If no such records exist, do you have any idea of how I might go about creating them?

I'm on arch linux, but I would be interested in answers to otherlinux distros as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to this content [check process](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-check-how-long-a-process-has-been-running/) to show you long you use your apps or program.

> applications are displaying content on my screen

for that condition you can search by the apps name which give output.